# What is the script that executes soon after we plug in AC adapter?

Tags: power-management, fan

My Dell Inspiron laptop's fan makes a lot of noise when i execute any heavy application process. The fan continues to make the noise till i plug in the AC adaptor power cord with power in.

It suddenly stops the noise when i plugin, i want to know what is happening, what script is it calling to stop the noise so i might execute it myself when it occurs again.

I need to know the script that runs soon after i connect the power in, so i might execute it manually without connecting the power cord in each time to stop the fan's noise.

I hope you guys understand what's happening, Thanks for the help in Advance.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Check `/etc/pm/power.d` and `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d`.

Comment: I installed "psensor" and "indicator-cpufreq" ... to change quickly the cpu when the temperature gets too high. Also "tlp" is installed running as power managment.  Under /etc/default/tlp you can change some parameters then, so you powermanagment can remember what you want.

Comment: In general from the symptoms that you have described, probably the fan is not functioning normaly, if you have valid warranty, I suggest you visit the Dell maintenance.